# How do I connect to a simple linux console for executing some basic commands that anyone could with just a linux operating system?

Tags: linux, command-line, command, putty

I would just like to be able to have my own linux command line on Windows 7. I do have Putty installed but I have no idea how to access a simple linux command line. I just basically need the basic commands that any Linux OPERATING SYSTEM has.

Comment: It depends. You could install something like Git Bash that will provide some common linux utilities on your windows machine. Alternatively, you could spin up a linux virtual machine and SSH into it to do linux-y things. You could even purchase a virtual private linux box and ssh in there. Lots of options. However I believe this question is more suitable for Super Users SE rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: Take a look at MinGW.

Answer (score 1):

Install Cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com). Cygwin is a Unix-like environment and command-line interface for Microsoft Windows. Cygwin provides native integration of Windows-based applications, data, and other system resources with applications, software tools, and data of the Unix-like environment.